# How to use a C struct as an argument when calling a C function from R?

Tags: c, r, struct, native

I'm currently working on calling C code from R - simple stuff like calculating some value from a passed integer works fine, but for my next piece of code I need to go a bit deeper.
In my C code, I use a custom C struct which holds pointers to various stuff the function works with, but what type does a C struct correspond to in R, since I figure I need to initialize it somehow?
Or would I rather add another abstraction layer that takes no arguments, is called by R, then initializes the struct normally and calls the function needing the struct internally?